# Access specific part of JSON JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am trying to access the `t` part of the `"data":` object below. I am doing this by doing `console.log(message.data.f)` however this returns `undefined`. I do not understand why I cannot access it in this way. See object below:

```
  "data":"{\"e\":\"53845\",\"f\":\"SCORE\",\"pf\":[{\"p\":\"HOME\",\"v\":\"0\"},{\"p\":\"AWAY\",\"v\":\"0\"}],\"^t\":\"f\",\"i\":\"357575\",\"z\":1492771602631}",
```

Note I have marked the part of the object I wish to access with a `^`

Comment: That's not even valid JSON to start with.

Comment: I know it is not I have deliberately left the other parts out to minify the amount of useless JSON i need to post.

Comment: You can remove the irrelevant parts and still leave something that is actual  valid JSON (preferably formatted and without a bunch of escaping). Help people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data property is a JSON string and probably all the object is a JSON string.
You need to parse the string as JSON

`var obj = JSON.parse(myObj.data);`

and then you can access:

```
console.log(obj.f);
```

If your first object, the one containing data, is not already a JSON too and its name is for example myFirstObject you need to do just this:

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(myFirstObject);
console.log(jsonObj.f);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your message is nothing but string. Parse it first to a corresponding object to access its variables.

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(message);
console.log(message.data.t);
```